# Whats the difference in Rails when a class is in quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I've noticed a couple examples in Rspec and FactoryGirl where some people put the class name in quotes, and some don't.

Example rspec:

```
describe "User" do
...specs...
end

describe User do
...specs...
end
```

Example FactoryGirl

```
factory :high_school_account, class: "Account" do
  Name "Test Account Name"
  AccountTypeId 1
end

factory :high_school_account, class: Account do
  Name "Test Account Name"
  AccountTypeId 1
end
```

I thought I read somewhere it had to do when the class is loaded into the ruby environment, but I might be completely making that up.

Is there a difference between the quoted and non-quoted versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the factory_girl [source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb#L22):

```
module FactoryGirl
  class Factory
    # ...
    def build_class
      @build_class ||= if class_name.is_a? Class
        class_name
      else
        class_name.to_s.camelize.constantize
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So no, in this context there is no difference - both are accepted. A String is simply converted to the class. Even a symbol would work.